# Django: Can't resolve an URL pattern from urls.py

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

My problem is the following:
Inside my urls.py I have defined these url patterns:

```
url(r'^image/upload', 'main.views.presentations.upload_image'),
url(r'^image/upload-from-url', 'main.views.presentations.upload_image_from_url'),
```

the problem is when I call from my browser the URL
    myowndomain:8000/image/upload-from-url
Django always execute the first pattern (r'^image/upload')

Is there any solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django uses the first matching pattern, and your `^image/upload` pattern doesn't include anything to stop it matching the longer text. The solution is to require that your pattern also match the end of the string:

```
r'^image/upload$'
```

By convention, Django URLs generally have a trailing slash as well, but that's not strictly required:

```
r'^image/upload/$'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert the dollar sign "$" at the end of the pattern. The dollar sign is a character that represents position. In the case of regex, this is the end of the string. Because both `image/upload` and `image/upload-from-url` match what you're looking for, you need to explicitly say where to stop in the pattern.